# Use ffmpeg to add a mp3 into the middle of the another mp3

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have two mp3 files.

I'd like to give a time stamp, say 15secs, then run a ffmpeg command to insert the first mp3 into the second mp3 at its 15secs time stamp.

The output time line is like this:

<---- 15sec 2nd mp3---> <---entire first mp3---> <--- the rest of 2nd mp3--->

How can I make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  the `concat` format. Create a file called `mymp3s.ffconcat`, containing

```
file 'first.mp3'
outpoint 15
file 'second.mp3'
file 'first.mp3'
inpoint 15
```

Then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mymp3s.ffconcat [other parameters to your liking] output.mp3
```

Comment: `[other parameters to your liking]` should at least include some compression-related options so that there will not be too much compression loss in the output file, e.g. `-c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k` or similar.